# Hard drive contents not showing in GIMP (Windows 10)

Tags: gimp

I installed GIMP 2.10.0 yesterday. When I try to open files, there are a few folders listed, such as "Documents" and "Pictures" as well as the letters of the hard drives. When clicking on a listed folder, the contents show up fine, but when clicking on any of the hard drives, it shows absolutely nothing. I tried running as administrator, but to no avail. Restarting the PC did nothing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a bug in GTK+, unless it is something deliberate (similar to the default Windows Explorer setting which hides system directories from the user).

For the moment it's being tracked in the GIMP Bug Tracker:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=795855

Typing a drive letter - i.e. c:\, d:\, ... - in the location bar is a workaround, as this open a dropdown of possible completions.

Comment: The workaround works for me, thanks. Hopefully this will be fixed soon. If I weren't tech savvy I would just give up on GIMP immediately